# WinEdt 8.0 Configuration - PDF Viewer

Tags: winedt

When I compile and run my pdf, I get my output like this. How do I rectify this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'rectify'? What's wrong with this output? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @AdamLiter, it is not rendering perfectly, see the title of the dialog box resume.pdf -- PS_View. This is similar to something viewing the dvi file but I want only the pdf format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download and install](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html) `sumatrapdf`.

Go to `Options` → `Execution Modes`. In the window that opens, select `PDF Viewer` as in this picture:

[image]

Search for the sumatrapdf executable (as in number 2) and press `OK`.

Now your pdf file will be opened in sumatrapdf.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Solved.......... :)